# How to start new game using JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I have such a game with balls and I'm trying to create `JMenuBar`.

I have a problem with the button `New`. Now the game starts immediatelly when I run my program, and when I click the button `New` the game opens again in the new window. I have a problem with this method: `fileNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener()`. This method runs the game again in the new window, it's not correct.

My goal is: When I run my program at first I see the blank table, and only after clicking the button `New` it starts (balls appears). If I click the button `New` during the game it starts again in the same window. How can I achieve this?

[image]

My code:

```
package api;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.*;
import gui.Render;
import database.SaveGame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

public Main() {

    // ------menu------//
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
    JMenuItem fileNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    fileNew.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    JMenuItem fileSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    fileNew.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    JMenuItem fileLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
    fileSave.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

    JMenuItem fileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    fileExit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    fileExit.setToolTipText("Exit application");
    fileExit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));

    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");

       // website button action
    about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            launchURL("https://www.kurnik.pl/kulki/zasady.phtml");
        }
    });

    // ---new---//
    fileNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String[] value = null;
            Main.main(value);
                }
    });

    // ---exit---//
    fileExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    fileMenu.add(fileNew); // file
    fileMenu.add(fileLoad); // load
    fileMenu.add(fileSave); // save
    fileMenu.addSeparator(); // ____
    fileMenu.addSeparator(); // ____
    fileMenu.add(fileExit); // exit
    helpMenu.add(about);

    menubar.add(fileMenu);
    menubar.add(helpMenu);

    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    int width = Game.widthSize * Render.SCALE;
    int height = Game.heightSize * Render.SCALE;
    Game game = new Game();
    add(new Render(game, width, height));

    setTitle("Kulki");
    setSize(width + 18, height + 38);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

static void launchURL(String s) {
    String s1 = System.getProperty("os.name");
    try {

        if (s1.startsWith("Windows")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec((new StringBuilder()).append("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler ").append(s).toString());
        } else {
            String as[] = {"firefox", "opera", "konqueror", "epiphany",
                "mozilla", "netscape"};
            String s2 = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < as.length && s2 == null; i++) {
                if (Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"which", as[i]}).waitFor() == 0) {
                    s2 = as[i];
                }
            }

            if (s2 == null) {
                throw new Exception("Could not find web browser");
            }
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{s2, s});
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("An error occured while trying to open the web browser!\n");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Main ms = new Main();
            ms.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: *I have a problem with this method* Please elaborate on what this problem is.  And while you're at it, please remove the screengrab and the code that is not that method, because all those do is create unnecessary noise.

Comment: Yes, please specify what the problem is. What your 'New' menu item is doing right now is creating a new instance of Menu. You might want to consider adding a method called `reset` or `restart` to the game, and calling that method instead.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't pass `null` to `main`.  Instead, what you should be doing it figuring out away to pass a new instance of `Game` to `Render`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Most of that code is irrelevant to the immediate problem, yet it won't compile due to missing classes that might be relevant. 2) **Create a `GameModel` on which the state / look of the GUI is based. When resetting the game, reset the model and call `repaint()` on the GUI component that draws it.** 3) Other tips: Don't extend GUI components unless necessary (there is not good reason to extend `JFrame`. Give classes meaningful, specific & descriptive names. E.G. `Main` -> `XyzGameMain`